# How to show summary in node view?

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

While adding article, I am having an option to enter summary for article. But this summary is not displaying in node view. I wanted summary to be displayed in full node view.

Any ideas how can I show summary in full node view?

-- Many thanks for your time.

Comment: do you want to show summary only or both body and summary together

Comment: I wanted to show both. First summary followed by full body. So that first by reading summary, reader may know the content of article.

Comment: add this "print drupal_render( field_view_field('node', $node, 'safe_summary') );" to hook_node_view() in a custom module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,but I solved it, and explained in the answer. tc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by overriding node template for my content type.

1) Copied `node.tpl.php` of my theme and renamed it to 
`node--content_type.tpl.php`.

2) Put the following code at desired place:

```
<div class="fullmode_summary">
    <?php if ($view_mode == 'full'): ?>
      <?php print render($node->body[$node->language][0]['safe_summary']);  ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

May help someone having same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a bit differently as I had 8 content types that needed the summary and they were displayed in different places in the node.
first add a dynamic field in display suite, choose node:tokens then summary.
then add this code to template.php

```
function themename_preprocess_node(&$vars) {

//adding the summary field to the node via DS results in a field that displays 'summary or trimmed'
//what is needed is 'summary or nothing' because the body is already displayed
if($vars['view_mode'] == 'full') {
    $object = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $vars['node']);
    if(!empty($vars['content']['body'])) {
        //get the value of the summary field
        $summary_value = $object->body->summary->value();
        //if there is no summary remove the trimmed body text from the summary field
        if(empty($summary_value)) {
            unset($vars['content']['summary']);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use 'display suite'.

1. enable display suite extras
2. map the summary field.

In addition to display suite, this requires the token module.

Map by, adding a custom field via the tabs on the bottom left of *manage display*

1. List item
2. Then *add a code field*
3. Add a label
4. Bind it to *Node*
5. Enter the text [node:summary]
6. Check the *Token* box

You can then add the field you just created to your display.

[image: How to add the custom field using display suite]